# Encoded URL in htaccess 301 redirect (mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am lost after digging into this matter for a lot of days. We have the following redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^something/something2/?$ http://test.com/blabla?key=blablabla1287963%3D [R=301,L,E=OUTLINK:1]
Header always set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=OUTLINK
```

Unfortunately that %3D got stripped by the module (mod_rewrite). The main problem is that I know how to manually fix it but I have multiple similar redirects and I need a "global solution". Please note that moving back to redirect 301 (I had no issues with redirect 301 and encoded URLs/characters) is not an option since I want to use noindex... 
Thank you!

Comment: Does the `B` flag help? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: No this won't help.

Comment: How exactly did you figure it got “stripped”, and that it was mod_rewrite doing it?

Comment: "I know how to manually fix it" - what do you mean by this? How would you "manually fix it"?

Comment: By manually I mean using backslash to literally use the %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that `%3D` got stripped by the module

I think you'll find that it's the `%3` that gets stripped, not `%3D`. `%3` is seen as a backreference to a preceding condition - which I suspect doesn't exist - so gets replaced with an empty string in the *substitution*. (This would not have been a problem with `Redirect` since `%N` backreferences aren't a thing with mod_alias.)

You need to backslash escape the `%` to represent a literal `%` in the *substitution* string in order to negate its special meaning in this case.

You will then need the `NE` flag on the `RewriteRule` to prevent the `%` itself from being URL encoded (as `%25`) in the response (essentially doubly encoding the URL param value).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ http://test.com/blabla?key=blablabla1287961\%3D [NE,R=302,L,E=OUTLINK:1]
```

> I have multiple similar redirects and I need a "global solution"

As far as a "global solution" goes, there isn't a magic switch you can enable on the server that will "fix" this. You need to modify each directive where this *conflict* occurs.